no stdout when running an npm script from within vscode
When I run an NPM script from the commandline like this
npm run myscript

it works fine.
vscode shows all scripts in the explorer view.
If I run the same 'myscript' by clicking this script in the explorer view, the tool  (written in javascript) that is called by 'myscript' crashes. That tool tries to do a command and read the stdout data, but it recieves nothing.
Why does it get data when I start the script from the command line, but not when I start it from within vscode?
the package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-updatedependencies2latest": "^0.0.20"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "u2l": "./u2l.sh"
  }
}


the script (u2l.sh):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

scriptDir=`realpath $(dirname "$0")`

npx update2latest "$scriptDir" dependencies

the error message when starting from withing vscode:
error while executing /home/corno/workspace/test123/node_modules/.bin/update2latest
working directory: /home/corno/workspace/test123
the command that was run: `npm pkg get "dependencies" --prefix /home/corno/workspace/test123`
the output of the command is not valid JSON: ''


Can you please post the script and package.json in question? What is the error message you see when myscript crashes within vscode?

@htor: consider it done

Are you sure scriptDir gets the right value always? Running the script from VSCode could change the current working directory, thus changing the expression realpath $(dirname .... Does npm pkg get "dependencies" --prefix /home/corno/workspace/test123 produce valid JSON if you run the command manually in the terminal?

@htor yes it does. As long as it is in the terminal, everything seems to work. I checked the scriptDir variable by adding an echo to the script; vscode does not change the current working directory: /home/corno/workspace/test123
